# VoiceOver Scrolls to Top of Page when iFrame Receives Focus

Tags: ios, iframe, accessibility, voiceover

I've been trying to work this out for a while but I keep coming to a dead end.

**Scenario:**

I have a youtube video embedded in an iframe on my page.

I am able to play the video just fine on my Mac when using voiceover however on my iPhone 6 and an iPad, when I use VoiceOver and the swipe gestures to move through the page and attempt to play the video, the viewport scrolls to the top of the page when focus reaches VoiceOver.

[Here is a gif that is currently happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeIbD.gif)

Incidentally, this problem doesn't occur when the youtube video is one of the first items on the page, it only happens when the video is below the fold as it were. The current has JS to make the heigh of all the divs the same.

I should mention I have seen this previous question and indeed attempted to implement it but the issue was still occurring.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.